# Ubuntu 14.04 fresh install disabled toshiba satellite fans

Tags: 14.04, fan

With a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 my fan is not working.  After searching the forums I tried:

```
sudo sensors-detect
Intel digital thermal sensor...Sucess!

Trying family 'SMSC'...Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x3503
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
...National...No
...SMSC...    No
...VIA/Win... No
...ITE...     No
Probing for...KCS'... No
Probing for...SMIC'...No
Driver 'i2c-i801' fo device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel 8281G ICH7
Module i2c0i801 loaded successfully.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.
```

Chip drivers and coretemp module lines added automatically.
Temps look fine, but fan is not running. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try Toshiba hardware interface package - toshset

```
sudo apt-get install toshset
```